# Replication in SQL Server 2008 R2 if Source and Destination Tables indexes are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

To fine tune the performance of overall system, I was checking the existing table's Indexes and found that we are using a ErrorLog table which is hit(for writing warnings and errors) for millions of transactions everyday. As we have indexes(on datetime) on this kind of table I thought this logging will definitely takes longer than the logging in to table without any indexes.

The whole indexing on CreateDateTime is used only by Developers for querying the table for troubleshooting in Production environment. Is it possible to take out index on the primary production server and have index only for the table in secondary(backup) db server. As we are doing replication on secondary server data is always in Sysc.

To Sync both the tables via replication, do we need to have same indexes on both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming transactional replication, there is nothing saying that the indexes have to be the same between the publisher and the subscriber. The only thing that you need to keep is the primary key as that's how replication identifies what row(s) on the subscriber need to be affected by a given statement at the publisher.